# How to create a successive sequence column in a data frame in R?

Tags: r, dplyr, sequence

I am currently working on the [booking.com challenge](https://www.bookingchallenge.com/) and the current dataset in small column wise. I am attempting to create additional columns from the existing dataset. See below for a sample of the dataset. What I am attempting to do is create a "leg" column which in other words means what leg of the trip was this.

One utrip_id will have multiple cities and we know what was the first, second, and last cities visited because of the check in and check out dates. As an example, I simple want to create an additional column by utrip_id that states this is the first leg of the trip, second leg, and so on. Ideally the result would look like the orange table below. It would be great if the solution can be shown in dplyr, however if not I am happy with an alternative solution

[image]

[image]

Comment: What did you already try to achieve your goal? Can you share some code?

Comment: I have not tried; I did not know where to start with this problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could simply use the rank function.

```
set.seed(1)
df <- data.frame(checkin = sample(seq(as.Date('1999/01/01'), as.Date('2000/01/01'), by="day"), 12),
                 utrip_id = rep(1:4, each = 3))

df %>%
  group_by(utrip_id) %>%
  mutate(leg_of_trip = rank(checkin))
```

which gives:

```
# A tibble: 12 x 3
# Groups:   utrip_id [4]
   checkin    utrip_id leg_of_trip
   <date>        <int>       <dbl>
 1 1999-11-20        1           3
 2 1999-06-16        1           2
 3 1999-05-09        1           1
 4 1999-10-26        2           3
 5 1999-09-27        2           2
 6 1999-07-06        2           1
 7 1999-11-03        3           3
 8 1999-03-26        3           1
 9 1999-10-04        3           2
10 1999-11-26        4           3
11 1999-09-20        4           1
12 1999-11-25        4           2
```

Comment: that did the trick, idk why I didnt think of this. I do it all the time in SQL. Check mark!